# Power Query using a list of 185 URLs only returns data from the first URL - 185 times

Tags: list, url, parameters, powerbi, powerquery

Hi I hope someone can please help or advise.

I am very new to Power BI and am using version 2.88.802 as this works OK with Win 7.

I am aiming to extract a single value from each of 158 similar URLs so I have created a query to an Excel file containing the URLs in a table, then made a copy of the table and converted this to a list of URLs.

I have then created a parameter of Type text, and Suggested Values query, which uses the list as the query, and has the first URL as the Current Value.

I then have a further query as a column that returns the value required from the first URL, then edited to swap the list for the single URL.

I do get 158 values returned, but they are all the same - correspond to the first URL. I do hope someone can please advise a solution. I've put some details I hope are relevant below (but I think the forum rules may have mangled some of the html)

This is the query to get the value:

```
let
Source = Web.BrowserContents(Parameter1),
#"Extracted Table From Html" = Html.Table(Source, {{"Column1", ".mod-tearsheet-overview__quote__bar > :nth-child(1) > .mod-ui-data-list__value"}}),
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Extracted Table From Html",{{"Column1", type number}})
in
#"Changed Type"
```

This is the first URL:

https://markets.ft.com/data/funds/tearsheet/summary?s=GB00BYY0KS10:GBP

The value I'm trying to extract is

PRICE (GBP)0.99

which I got to using Add Table Using Examples

Comment: Is your question how top use  the right `CSS Selector`, or how to request 100 pages? If it's the latter, we're missing the rest of your query. The code above has no functions declared.